# How do I resolve `raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: [SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_HERE]` while uploading file to slack using python?

Tags: python, slack

Here is my code to send a pdf file to my slack workspace. But it produces error.

```
client = WebClient(token=os.environ[SLACK_BOT_TOKEN])

try:
    filepath = "./output.pdf"
    response = client.files_upload(channels='#mychannelid_here', file=filepath)
    assert response["file"]  # the uploaded file
except SlackApiError as e:
    # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
    assert e.response["ok"] is False
    assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
    print(f"Got an error: {e.response['error']}")
```

Error is :

> raise KeyError(key) from None
> KeyError: SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_HERE

Thanks in advance for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use [getenv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getenv-method/) with a default (if it makes sense).

```
import os

SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = 'SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'
DEFAULT_SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_VALUE = 'Hello Slack'
token = os.getenv(SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, DEFAULT_SLACK_BOT_TOKEN_VALUE)
print(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refer to a variable `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` but your code does not define a variable with this name.

Probably you mean `token=os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]` where the literal string `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` is looked up in the environment (so you should have an environment variable with this name, and now you are looking it up).

A common arrangement is to store the token in a place where it is not saved in your code (so kept out of your `git` repository etc) and require you to set it in the environment before running Python.  So, for example

```
bash$ secrettoken="your token here"
bash$ export secrettoken
bash$ python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["secrettoken"])'
your token here
```

This works similarly (though not exactly the same) on Windows, with the usual different syntax and weird corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I have defined my slack bot token at the beginning of the code inside a variable `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN `. And I also tried placing my token inside `token=os.environ["token here"]` , but both doesn't seems working.

Comment: Then probably you mean `token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN`; but the error message in the question suggests that you have not defined this variable properly. The absolutely simplest fix is `token="token here"`. (Though the question is not very well-formatted. The full traceback would be better.) The meaning of `os.environ["string"]` is to fetch an environment variable whose name is `string`; if you have not defined an environment variable which contains the token then obviously don't try to fetch one.

Comment: Instead of `os.environ("SLACK_TOKEN_STRING")` I used `os.getenv(SLACK_TOKEN_VARIABLE)` and the problem was solved. Thanks for your time and help !

Comment: Putting the name of the other variable in a variable seems like overkill, but more power to you. I updated the answer slightly.